# Moving packages from default user R library path to custom folder in windows

Tags: r

There are several questions related to mine, but I was not able to find a satisfying answer to this. During installation of R (4.3), it sets the default path as `C:\Program Files\R\R-4.3.2\library`, which unfortunately in windows it is not writable by user (unless you have admin privileges). So when trying to install a package and getting an "unable to write" error, it looks like a new path is added to the deafults, `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3`.

I am not sure how this new path gets set in R and its made as the default, but I was not able to find a reference to the "AppData" folder in any of the `Rcmd_environ` or `Rprofile.site` under `C:\Program Files\R\R-4.3.2\etc`.

What would be the appropriate way to change the default user library (in windows) from  `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3` to `C:\MyPATH\R\win-library\4.3`, and what would be the order of steps so that the packages are successfully moved from the "AppData" library to my "MyPATH"?